Should video embedding be enabled?
On the gaming SE site YouTube videos are automatically embedded into answers. Could we get something like that too?
It would be very useful for showing mechanical parts/creations in action, especially LEGO robotics.

I'm honestly not completely certain whether we still offer this option, but if it is desired, I would encourage you to make a new Meta post to discuss it.

The best way to make a case for this is to demonstrate a need for video on this site. If video would improve your answer, start linking to videos in your posts!
Assuming they're actually useful, this provides some concrete data for judging how and where they're appropriate, lets you create guidelines for their use, and lets us see that adding support for embedding them directly would be beneficial to the site.

That makes sense - so far the only questions where I feel this would help would be [tag:technique] questions where someone would want to illustrate a step-by-step build process, but even then I think showing one image for each step would be appropriate in most cases.

70 days into beta we have 19 answers and 6 questions that include at least one link to Youtube. The most popular tags associated with these posts tend to be mindstorms, building and power-functions.*
Questions based on robotics and mechanics tend to include videos, which can help explain a complex mechanism. A video alone isn't usually enough to answer a question so users should be encouraged to expand on important points.
* The search term used was url:"*.youtube.*" combined with is:question or is:answer
